# How to use LIKE with ANY in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Is there a way to do a partial string match on a string array column in postgres?

I'm trying the following syntax, but it is not working as I'd expect it to:

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE '%partial string' ILIKE ANY(array_column)
```

Is there a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists temp_a;
create temp table temp_a as
(
    select array['alpha','beta'] as strings
    union all
    select array['gamma','theta']
);

select * 
from (select unnest(strings) as string from temp_a) as sq 
where string ilike '%eta'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to search each subscript separately -- here's an example that can be expounded on to include more columns

```
SELECT distinct array_column FROM
   (SELECT array_column,
           generate_subscripts(array_column, 1) AS s
      FROM example_table) AS foo
 WHERE array_column[s] like '%partial string';
```

Alternative hack:

```
select * from example_table where array_column::text like '%partial%'
```

if necessary you could hack "partial" to include the opening/closing brackets and quotes to be just a bit more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Just implemented this using [`array_to_string`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE array_to_string(array_column) ILIKE '%partial string'
```